# Gem Issue, Database Rake Aborted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am looking to rake my database and boot my server, but get the following issues when i look to rake the database:

```
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/lib/ruby_debug.bundle, 9):     Symbol not found: _ruby_current_thread
```

and two lines specifying the same issue of `Symbol not found: _ruby_current_thread`:

```
Referenced from: /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/lib/ruby_debug.bundle
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/lib/ruby_debug.bundle
```

`Expected in: flat namespace`

Can't seem to find the issue with this, thanks guys for your help in advance.

Comment: It seems odd that ruby-debug is being called at all. Perhaps you could try to remove it from the process?

Comment: @Emily thank you for your response. how do i go about removing ruby_debug? I'm relatively seasoned in rails but ive never experienced this type of issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some known problems with ruby 1.9.3 and ruby debug. You have two options. Instead of using ruby-debug you can use the debugger gem which is a fork of ruby debug and works on ruby 1.9.3. It's github page is [here](https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger).

```
gem 'debugger'
```

If you want to stay with ruby debug you are going to need to get the pre-release versions(after removing the version you are currently using.):

```
gem install ruby-debug-base19x --pre
gem install ruby-debug-ide --pre
```

Gemfile:

```
gem 'ruby-debug-base19x', '0.11.30.pre10'
gem 'ruby-debug-ide', '0.4.17.beta9'
```

Cheers,
Sean

Comment: Worked like a charm. Using Bundler to manage dependencies, I only had to replace `gem 'ruby-debug19'` with `gem 'debugger'` an rerun `bundle install` to get this solved.